# how exclude names from a variable list?

Tags: powershell

I have this line of code:   `$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq "True") -and (OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

It works and it gets all of our servers.  I then ping each machine and get some data via WMI and from AD.   The issue is 4 of the servers that get returned completely hang my PowerShell script.  I know which ones they are, they all start with MKMK1xxxx

What I wanted to do is exclude these somehow in my script.   My $servers variable has all the servers but how would I then exclude these?

If ($servers -contains "*MKNK1*') {start-sleep -m 1} ELSE {continue doing stuff}  so far this logic has not worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an additional filter on your search:

```
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq "True") -and (OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*") -and (name -notlike "MKMK1*")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Edit: Also be careful with contains, here's [an article on that](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains)